# What is the correct way of getting the default JLabel dimensions?

Tags: java, swing

In order to solve a problem I am currently working on, I need to find out what is the default height of a JLabel. I am using a dummy approach:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
Dimension dim = label.getPreferredSize();
```

Is there a way to get the default height without instantiating JLabel?

Comment: What is the problem with specifying text? Why do you think you need this? If the know the reason maybe we can suggest a better approach.

Comment: JLabel("your text here") decides size according to input string.

Comment: @camickr, I simply need to find out what is the height given to JLabel by default in order to use that value to build the whole GUI, as it depends in this value...

Comment: @DejanLekic, that is NOT the way to build a GUI. You should be using layout managers. You should not need to know the height of any component in advance. The approach to your problem seems incorrect and you still haven't stated a requirement.

Comment: @camickr, I am actually developing a LayoutManager implementation... I thought hardcoding dimension is not a good idea, since the L&F definitely has some "clues" what dimensions to set by default. - No worries, I will check how default layout managers do this.

Comment: @DejanLekic, `I am actually developing a LayoutManager implementation` That is why I didn't understand the question (and asked for more information). LayoutManagers deal with real components so the layout manager will indeed know the preferred size at the time the layout manager is invoked. `I will check how default layout managers do this` - start with the BorderLayout, GridLayout or FlowLayout as they are the simplest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to find out what is the default height of a JLabel. I am using
>   a dummy approach:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
Dimension dim = label.getPreferredSize();
```

- is possible but you have to accept that this is done by LayoutManager, then there are two options

  1. Swing/AWT GUi is already visible on the screen
  2. after JFrame.pack() is called
- (I don't suggest, just for wroting a complete answer) is possible to get getPreferredSize for most of JComponents by using/invoke

  1. NullLayout by using Insets
  2. revalidate() and repaint() in already visible Swing/AWT GUI

> Is there a way to get the default height without instantiating JLabel?

- without incorectly settting by setSize, setPreferredSize, setBounds only by override getPreferredSize